# Facebook login with inappbrowser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement Facebook login in a web app that is rendered in an inappbrowser of Cordova. With fb.login() I receive a white screen in inappbrowser but all work fine in a chrome browser.

Okay after search in the community I find that Facebook recommends a manual flow.

Then I continue using Facebook API but I login with get call to Facebook connect asking for a token and a redirect....

That is my actual situation, but with standards browsers it redirect my to the app with a token and automatically refresh and token disappear and Facebook API works.

But with inappbrowser the login redirect my to my app with the token in the url and NOT redirect my and the API not work. for some reason i have the app with the token in the url but API Facebook not take it and refresh.

in addition in the logout i need to force fb* cookie to delete for can re-login (this is not a problem now but it was weird).

Comment: why not use a cordova plugin for the facebook api? afaik there are plugins for that, you should use those instead of trying to use the default js sdk.

Comment: the problem is that cordova only render in inappbrowse a webpage that is the full app if i login with cordova the webpage will not be logged

Comment: finnally i leave this solution, and i use restfb in the server side for make a personal login flow with facebook.